# Sum of $\frac{1}{5}-\frac{2}{5^2}+\frac{3}{5^3}-\frac{4}{5^4}+....$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of following series:

$S=\frac{1}{5}-\frac{2}{5^2}+\frac{3}{5^3}-\frac{4}{5^4}+....$ upto infinite terms

Could someone give me slight hint to solve this question?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647587/sum-of-a-power-series-n-xn

Comment: @graydad Yes, Thanx for pointing that out.

Comment: Even-powered terms are not in G.P. the next even term is $-6/5^6$, not $-8/5^6$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$S=\frac 15-\frac2{5^2}+\frac 3{5^3}-\dots\tag 1$$
and $$\frac S5=\frac 1{5^2}-\frac2{5^3}+\frac 3{5^4}-\dots\tag 2$$

Now, $(1)+(2)$ yields $$S+\frac S5=\frac 15-\frac1{5^2}+\frac1{5^3}+\dots\\\implies \frac{6S}5=\frac 15-\frac1{5^2}+\frac1{5^3}+\dots=\frac 16\\\implies S=\frac5{36}.$$

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**. One may recall ([see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn/1706005#1706005)) that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2},\quad |x|<1.
$$ Then apply it with $x=-\dfrac15$.