# How to calculate this $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}e^{jwn}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fourier-transform

How to calculate this $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}e^{-jwn}$,because it is not geometric progression,so i can't know how to solve it,can anyone help me?

Comment: Still you can write your series as $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{e^{-jwn}}{2^n}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{e^{-jwn}}{2^n}+\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{e^{-jwn}}{2^n}+\ldots $$ which is a geometric series of geometric series.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647587/sum-of-a-power-series-n-xn

Answer (score 2):

For $|z|<1$ we have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n z^n= \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$.

Now let $z= \frac{e^{-jw}}{2}$. Can you proceed ?

Comment: thx,i will see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647587/sum-of-a-power-series-n-xn