# Is there any. elementary formula for the sequence$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(2k-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}$

Tags: summation

Is there any formula for the following sequence which does not use any derivative and also is less 
advanced:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(2k-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}$$
I've calculated the general formula 
and here is a photo of the solution
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMJNf.png): [image]

Comment: you can also use induction

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(2k-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}$$

then for the first term we can use the approch indicated here

- [Sum of a power series $n x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/647587/505767)

Comment: It seems that your solution uses derivative

Comment: @Absurd Refer to that [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647625/505767).

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly simple proof by induction.

$$\mathcal{H}_n \ : \ \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(2k-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k} = -2^{-n}(2n+3)+3\right\}$$

**Base case** is obvious, $\mathcal{H}_1$ is true.

**Induction**. Suppose $\mathcal{H}_n$ true. Now
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(2k-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(2k-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k} +(2n+1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}$$
By induction

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(2k-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k} &= -2^{-n}(2n+3) +3+(2n+1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}\\
&= \underbrace{-2^{-n}(2n+1)}_{A} -\underbrace{2^{-n}2}_{B} +\underbrace{(2n+1)2^{-n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}_{C} + 3\\
\end{align*}
$$
Summing $A$ and $C$, and rewriting $B$ as $2^{-n}2=2^{-(n+1)}4$ we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(2k-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k} = -2^{-(n+1)}(2n+5)+3$$
Hence $\mathcal{H}_{n+1}$ is true, and by induction principle,

$$\forall n\geq 1, \  \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(2k-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k} = -2^{-n}(2n+3)+3$$

**Edit - more direct approach** Using inspiration from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647587/sum-of-a-power-series-n-xn)
Let 
$$F_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nkx^k=x+2x^2+\ldots+nx^n$$
Then
$$F_n(x)-xF_n(x) = x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^n-nx^{n+1}$$
$$F_n(x)-xF_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^nx^k-nx^{n+1}$$
$$F_n(x)-xF_n(x) = x\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}-nx^{n+1}$$
So that
$$F_n(x) = x\frac{1-x^n}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{nx^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

Now, using @user remark, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(2k-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}$$

And

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}= 2F_n(1/2)-(1-2^{-n})$$
Using our formula for $F_n(x)$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}= 2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{1-2^{-n}}{(1/2)^2}-\frac{n2^{-(n+1)}}{1/2}\right) - (1-2^{-n})$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}= 4 (1-2^{-n}) - 4n2^{-(n+1)} - (1-2^{-n})$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}= 3 (1-2^{-n}) - 4n2^{-(n+1)}$$
And finally
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(2k-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k} = -2^{-n}(2n+3)+3$$

Comment: Thank you so much ,but is there another way which does not use induction?because before we use induction we need to know what exactly is the formula,after that we may use induction.

Comment: yes, I'm writing it at as Edit.

Comment: I'm put lots of details that's why the proof is a bit long, but is very simple at each step.