# Egorychev method how do you derive this geometric sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Example 2:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorychev_method#Example_II

How do you derive the closed-form result from the finite sum?

I tried it myself and the answer is way more complicated https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28k%3D1%29%5En++k*+%28z%2F%281-z%29%29%5Ek+

The leading 'k' value in the summation cannot just vanish like it does below? How does the k go away like that?

: 
\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}}
\sum_{k\ge 1} k \frac{z^k}{(1-z)^k}
\; dz \\[6pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}}
\frac{z/(1-z)}{(1-z/(1-z))^2}
\; dz \\[6pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^n}
\frac{1}{(1-2z)^2}
\; dz.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The $k$ goes away using [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/647587/215011)
$$
\sum _{n=1}^\infty nx^n = \frac x {(1-x)^2},
$$
which is valid when $|x|<1$.